# How to add c++ libraries to cloud9 c++ development environment

Tags: c++, cloud9-ide

I want to write a c++ program on cloud9, but the program has dependencies of third parties libraries such as boost and  apache xercesc.  How can I add this libraries to cloud9 development environment?

Answer (score 0):

You add dependencies the normal way you would on Linux. From the Bash console window just type: `sudo yum install boost-devel`